# How to keep expressions in HandleBars.Net for later evaluation?

Tags: handlebars.net

This seems to be a simple matter and maybe it's solved already, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'd like to keep arbitrary unresolved expressions for later evaluation. Note that I still don't know which expressions are already defined.

For example, suppose I have the expression...

```
{{source.path}}/mainmenu{{ext}}"
```

...and the context defines `ext` as `.js`, but `source.path` is still undefined. What I get is`/mainmenu.js"`, but I'd like to get `{{source.path}}/mainmenu.js"` instead so that I can evaluate `{{source.path}}` at a later time. `HandlebarsConfiguration.UnresolvedBindingFormatter` seemed promising, but it doesn't handle the complete original expression. `HandlebarsConfiguration.ExpressionNameResolver` also didn't help.

So, is it possible to do this at all? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi there, handlebars.net author here. At the time of this writing, that's not possible. Suggest you open an issue on Github or, even better, submit a pull request to add it!

Comment: I've requested the implementation of the "missing" hooks [here](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net/issues/350). In Handlebarsjs we successfully used the "missingHelper" to implement what you need.

Comment: Thanks, @sferencik. I've moved to Nunjucks for some time now 
because I realized I neeed more powerful templates. Good to know that Handlebars is evolving.